# Best way to compare values in single table

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I have a SQL server table which has data in following format.

```
ColumnA : ServerName
ColumnB : ObjectName
ColumnC : HashValue
```

What I need to do is compare values in ColumnC for each server based on ColumnB . Objective is to see which servers have the same objects with different hashes.

What we have done so far is split the table into multiple tables based on server name. So for table_one it would only contain data for server one.

Then we did the same for server two to table_two.

after this we did a left join from table_one to table_two because table_one had more entries.

From this point we could just to the following.

```
select * from table_one 
left join table_two
on table_one.ColumnB =table_two.ColumnB 
where table_one.ColumnC !=table_two.ColumnC
```

Issue with this is there are 10 servers with about 10 000 entries each at least and this is a slow process.

```
select * into table_one from table_one  where ColumnA ="ServerOne"
select * into table_two from table_one  where ColumnA ="ServerTwo"

select * from table_one 
left join table_two
on table_one.ColumnB =table_two.ColumnB 
where table_one.ColumnC !=table_two.ColumnC
```

I expect to see each object with a server name where it did not match hash from server one. Using server one as a base because it has most objects not necessarily exact same ones as the others do as well.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the WHERE clause condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @jarl, it will return also irrelevant rows with `table_one.ColumnC = table_two.ColumnC` . Instead allow `null` in `where`.

Comment: @RomanoBrooks . . . Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to split them into different tables. You can join a table with itself:

```
Select a.ColumnA from your_table a
inner join
your_table b on a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB and a.ColumnC != b.ColumnC
```

EDIT:

I don't know what the dependencies are on your table but just in case the objective is not unique just tweak the query to this:

```
Select a.ColumnA from your_table a
inner join
your_table b on a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA = a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB and a.ColumnC != b.ColumnC
```

Though if you're going to need the statement a lot I would recommend cleaning your tables up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Compare all at once, show missing objects or different `ColumnC`

```
select t1.*, t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnC
from table_all t1
left join table_all t2
on t1.ColumnA < t2.ColumnA and t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB 
where t2.ColumnC is null or t1.ColumnC != t2.ColumnC
order by t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB
```

Answer (score 0):

> Objective is to see which servers have the same objects with different hashes.

You can get the list of servers and objects that differ using aggregation:

```
select ServerName, ObjectName
from t
group by ServerName, ObjectName
having min(HashValue) <> max(HashValue);
```

If you actually want the details, then I would recommend window functions:

```
select ServerName, ObjectName
from (select t.*,
             min(HashValue) over (partition by ServerName, ObjectName) as min_hashValue,
             max(HashValue) over (partition by ServerName, ObjectName) as max_hashValue
      from t
     ) t
where min_HashValue) <> max_HashValue
order by ServerName, ObjectName, hashValue;
```

I prefer this method because it produces a *list* of the values.  If you do this using a `JOIN`, then you will get lots of 2-way comparisons -- that just multiplies the number of rows you need to look at.